# DHTMLX scheduler recurring event id(id#timestamp) getting failed in DHTMLX functions

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am developing a recurring event feature in already working DHTMLX scheduler. I am able to insert the recurring event in my DB. When I try to update the event. It gives me error in setUpdated(), sendData() and getState() functions of DHTMLX javascript. As, these methods are working perfectly, in normal event_id(e.g: 132) but not working in recurring event_id(id#timestamp).
Please give me your advice.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The described issues occur because of the specific behavior of the recurring events. All series of the recurring events are technically the single event with the normal id, like `id: 1`. All other occurrences are parts of this event that don't exist till they won't be shown in the current view.
To they can't be accessed by the  `getEvent()` call if they don't display in the current view.

You can get the required event using the `getEvents(from ,to)` method:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_getevents.html
which "generates" all occurrences that should be displayed:
https://prnt.sc/1qgx1hl

Hope it will be easier to do the required thing with this info.
Also, you can check out the guide of updating occurrences by the following link:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/recurring_events.html#editingdeletingacertainoccurrenceintheseries